# Rows On Bootstrap modal-body have no gap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

On my bootstrap modal, I have two rows but they are all bunched up with no spacing, between the rows.

Question: Why is the rows on the bootstrap modal-body have no gap between them and what would be the best solution to solve it?

Code Preview [Click Here](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/RWVpEQ)

Full Preview [Click Here](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/full/RWVpEQ/)

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<hr>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Click To Open Modal
</button>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <a href="" id="button-parent" class="btn btn-default">Parent Folder</a> 
    <a href="" id="button-refresh" class="btn btn-default">Refresh Page</a>
    <button type="button" id="button-upload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
    <button type="button" id="button-folder" class="btn btn-default">Create Folder</button>
    <button type="button" id="button-delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_search; ?>" id="button-search" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to your use of `.row` in the modal. `.row`'s has no padding or margin. If you not want to change your markup, then a little "hack" could be

```css
.modal-body .row {
   padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

the above and your code in a fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zfLsmogx/**

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use form-elements in bootstrap, its recommended that, you put that specific element inside a form-group class - this way, there is a margin-bottom of 15px below every element.

> [As per Bootstrap's form example:](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example) Wrap labels and controls in .form-group for optimum spacing.

```css
.inline-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <hr>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Click To Open Modal
  </button>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group inline-group">
              <a href="" id="button-parent" class="btn btn-default">Parent Folder</a> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group inline-group">
              <a href="" id="button-refresh" class="btn btn-default">Refresh Page</a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group inline-group">
              <button type="button" id="button-upload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group inline-group">
              <button type="button" id="button-folder" class="btn btn-default">Create Folder</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group inline-group">
              <button type="button" id="button-delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="" class="form-control">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_search; ?>" id="button-search" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but, `form-group` is a **block** property, so, its gonna drop every form-element in new line, So either you can add another class like `.inline-group` and make it `display:inline-block` as shown

Comment: Your code is the best solution, but somehow I had the feeling that OP would stick to his markup.  +1